# WPF/MVVM: Notifying For Wrapped Model Properties In The ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

This is a question about MVVM best practice.

Let's say I've got a pair of properties F0 & F1 in my Model, such that F0 follows F1 (based on some logic):

```
class Model
{
    private float _f0;
    public float F0
    {
        get { return _f0; }
        private set 
        { 
           _f0 = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("F0");  //I know this isn't allowed - bear with me...
        }
    }

    private float _f1;
    public float F1
    {
        get { return _f1; }
        set
        {
           _f1 = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("F1");

           if(someLogic)
              F0 = F1;
        }
    }
}
```

If I've got an instance of Model in my ViewModel, I *could* make this work by binding directly to F0 (OneWay) and F1 (TwoWay), i.e.:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=modelInstance.F0, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
<Slider Value="{Binding Path=modelInstance.F1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Of course, that's not MVVM.  Better to wrap them & "flatten" the properties presented by the ModelView:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public float Model_F0
    {
        get{ return modelInstance.F0; }
    }
    public float Model_F1
    {
        get{ return modelInstance.F1; }
        set
        {
           modelInstance.F1 = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged("Model_F1");
        }
    }        
}
```

The binding then becomes:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Model_F0, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
<Slider Value="{Binding Path=Model_F1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The obvious issue here is that the View won't know when F0 gets changed, as it's bound to Model_F0 (and not directly to F0).  So my question is: what is the proper way to solve this?  In the first case I "break" the MVVM pattern by binding directly to properties within the model; in the second case the behavior is incorrect.

Note that the above is a highly simplified example; in reality "F1" may affect more properties than just "F0" (or none at all).  Thus explicitly raising Model_F0 in the Model_F1 setter isn't a workable solution; I'm looking for a more general way to handle such a scenario, where some of the Model's properties may affect others, and those properties need to be wrapped by the ViewModel for consumption by the View.

Comment: Why are you wrapping it into two layers in the first place though? Maybe you can move the model's validation into the VM? Will that work?

Comment: The Model is a shared DLL that's used in multiple other (WinForms) projects, so no, it needs to remain there...

Comment: The way I would handle this scenario is through an event having the ViewModel listening to the Model if it changes. This would raise the appropriate OnPropertyChanged() event handlers to notify what properties should update. The basic idea is to daisy chain the notifications.

Comment: So basically, the Model would have a unique Event for each possible property that could be updated by another property, the ViewModel would subscribe to those events, and in each event's handler it calls RaisePropertyChanged() for the corresponding "pass-through" property name in the VM?